# Попарное суммирование рядом стоящих чисел

Tags: java, коллекции

Необходимо с использованием множества просуммировать рядом стоящие числа в первый проход, затем в следующий проход взять результат первого и просуммировать попарно стоящие числа и т.д. до тех пор пока не останется одно число. С первым проходом всё понятно, но вот как сделать чтобы в последующие проходы всё суммировалось. Что имею:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TreeSet<Integer> treeSet1 = new TreeSet<>();
        writeRandomInSet(10, treeSet1);
        System.out.println(firstSummation(treeSet1));


    }
    public static TreeSet<Integer> writeRandomInSet(int n, TreeSet<Integer> treeSet){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            treeSet.add((int) (Math.random() * 20));
        }
        System.out.println(treeSet);
        return treeSet;
    }
    public static TreeSet<Integer> firstSummation(TreeSet<Integer> treeSet){
        TreeSet<Integer> sumTree = new TreeSet<>();
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = treeSet.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            int val = iterator.next();
            if (treeSet.higher(val) != null){
                int endVal = treeSet.higher(val) + val;
                sumTree.add(endVal);
                iterator.next();
            }
        }
        return sumTree;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно присвоить назад в `treeSet1` результат `firstSummation` и продолжать, пока не получится множество из одного элемента:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeSet<Integer> treeSet1 = new TreeSet<>();
    writeRandomInSet(10, treeSet1);
    while(treeSet1.size() > 1) {
        treeSet1 = firstSummation(treeSet1);
        System.out.println(treeSet1);
    }
}
```

Реализация `firstSummation` у вас немного странная. Эффективнее будет просто брать у итератора два значения подряд:

```
public static TreeSet<Integer> firstSummation(TreeSet<Integer> treeSet) {
    TreeSet<Integer> sumTree = new TreeSet<>();
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = treeSet.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        int val1 = iterator.next();
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            int val2 = iterator.next();
            sumTree.add(val1+val2);
        }
    }
    return sumTree;
}
```

Заметьте, что и в моей реализации, и в вашей, если на входе множество с нечётным числом элементов, то последний будет проигнорирован.

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш ответ помог в решении, а реализация `firstSummation` странная от того, что не имею большого опыта в программировании, исправил в соответствии с Вашей подсказкой